# IIS page loading forever

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I've inherited a .net application, my experience with IIS is limited.

For some reason, I cannot get the local environment to finish loading.

There doesn't seem to be any errors really. I've seen two, but I've read that one is more informational than an error and the other I'm thinking I get when I stop/start the site. Those errors are:

- `Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue`
- `Timer_ConnectionIdle`

I've been combing through the interwebs for a day and a half now and tried a panoply of things that it could be.

Things that I've tried (that I can remember)

- Checked the application pools and made sure they're using the correct version of .net.
- Re-added the default site to see if it loads (which it does)
- Changed the permissions of `web.config` so that the group "Everyone" has full access. I originally tried using IUSR or the Application pool identity, but it wasn't getting past a permissions error so I resorted Everyone.
- Verified that my bindings were added/applied correctly
- Verified that my bindings are in my hosts file.
- I get a successful ping to the binding
- I get a successful connection to the database in SQLServer.
- I've tried adding an `index.html` file to the root and loading that (endless loading)
- I've looked at the Event Viewer. I didn't see anything related to IIS or ASP.
- Tried the Failed Request Tracking. This doesn't seem to log anything at the moment.
- I've enabled all of the IIS > World Wide Web Services. Originally I was using the defaults.
- Recycled the application pools.
- The application requires .NET framework 4.5. I have 4.6 installed (though it doesn't show up in Windows Features. I've read that this is because WF only shows features that came bundled with the OS)
- I installed WAS and enabled all of its features.
- I've enabled both the HTTP and Non-HTTP Actication WCF features in Windows Features > Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1
- I've tried repairing .NET 4.6 install.
- Due to the `Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue` I've tried monitoring the Worker Processes. My Application Pool is there and it stays in the running state. There doesn't seem to be any requests that show up for it that last longer than 0 seconds.
- I've tried looking at w3wp.exe in resource monitor as well to see if anything was weird. It states that it's running normally.

I'm really at a loss here. The only thing I can think of is that I'm missing something or something isn't enabled from 4.6 that is necessary. The previous devs had .NET 4.6 Advanced Services listed in their Windows Features. I don't have that. It has ASP.NET 4.6 under it as well as WCF Services. Maybe they aren't getting enabled? I've scoured the web looking for ways to check if those things are enabled but nothing has led to an actual checkbox.

If it helps, I'm on Windows 7, with IIS 7.5, .NET v4.6

Comment: You've probably either got an error happening that you're missing, or you've got an infinite loop somewhere. You should add logging your application, starting with the code that runs on startup. Make sure it turns through to completion.

Comment: The thing is, I haven't modified the code, with the exception of the connection string. The other devs followed the same setup process that I did but theirs worked for some reason. The landing page doesn't even hit the database so I wouldn't think that would really matter. I'll definitely look into your suggestion though. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you didn't modify the code. It's dependencies could have changed, or it could be relying on some sort of external state.

Comment: Ahh - good call! I'll look into that.

Comment: Though shouldn't it still load a blank `index.html` file?

Comment: Probably not if the processing for that goes through the ASP.NET engine.

Comment: So after reinstalling .net 4.6, adding/changing some permissions around, I can load a blank index.html file. Sooo, some progress. Looks like there's a redirect loop happening now, but that's most likely a different issue.